# Python mocking global variable declared in another function

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am unit-testing a function which uses variable declared by other function.

```
def first_fun():
   global file_path
   file_path = get_file_path()
   .
   .

def second_fun():
   with open(file_path, "r") as flz:
   .
   .
```

How do I mock file_path while testing second_fun()?
I tried this but doesn't work.

```
   @patch.object(source_module, 'file_path')
   def test_second_fun(self):
          source_module.second_fun()
```

> I keep on getting ... does not have the attribute 'file_path'

Comment: The best solution would be not to use `global`, it is seen as an anti-pattern by many developers.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to consider:

First:

> Explicit is better than implicit

in this case, the file_path should be a function parameter.

Second:
for your test to be an **unit** test, you should patch open(), not a path, because you shouldn't depend on a external ressource.